# calculate average over multiple data frames?

Tags: r, function, sum, dataframe

I'd like to calculate the sum over two `data.frame`s.
Here is my `data.frame` U_data

```
ID    Rating
1     3.4
2     4.5
3     2.1
```

Here is my second `data.frame` M_data

```
M     Rating
M1    3.4
M2    2.9
M3    4.7
M4   5.0
```

I need to create new `data.frame` avg_data that add with corresponding data in above `data.frame` and minus 1. For example, for ID 1, M2, 3.4+ 2.9-1= 5.3.

```
ID    M1    M2    M3    M4
1     5.8   5.3  7.1   7.4
2
3
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your U_data is `df1` and M_data is `df2`):

```
res <- t(sapply(df1[,2], function(x) x + df2[,2]-1))
colnames(res) <- df2[,1]
data.frame(ID = df1[,1], res)
  ID  M1  M2  M3  M4
1  1 5.8 5.3 7.1 7.4
2  2 6.9 6.4 8.2 8.5
3  3 4.5 4.0 5.8 6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Does this work for you?
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, Rating = c(3.4, 4.5, 2.1))
df2 <- data.frame(M = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), Rating = c(3.4, 2.9, 4.7, 5.0))
answer <- outer(df1$Rating, df2$Rating, "+")
answer <- answer -1
colnames(answer) <- df2$M
rownames(answer) <- df1$ID
answer
```